# Adding an angular snippet of code in a jsf page

Tags: java, angularjs, jsf-2.2

I have a **javaee** application
I am using **jsf** with a single page application
Where i am controlling the hashchange of every page
I want to add page but which contains **angularjs** code and not jsf
Navigating to page is with a `<h:link>` that calls a `<a4j:jsFunction>` that will change a variable that is responsible on page view

I have a `<ui:include src="snippet/angularjs.xhtml" rendered="#{viewBean.view == 'angularjs'}">` where content will be ajax updated
The page angularjs.xhtml contains html and angularjs code and not jsf code
What's going is that when navigating to page snippet is show but angularjs tags are not compiled they still show `{{x}}` while if i refresh the page the **angularjs** code will be compiled

*Note : I don't want to use angularfaces*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `<a4j:jsFunction oncomplete="angular.bootstrap($('#id_of_angular_content'), ['idOfApp']);>`
and in angular page remove `ng-app` and give the `div` in snippet `id="id_of_angular_content"`